# Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'byte'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) when compile

Tags: c#

I`m not a guru in c and I need some help.
I have this code:

```
{
    private ushort InCounter;

    private ushort OutCounter;

    private byte[] cipherKey1 = new byte[256];

    private byte[] cipherKey2 = new byte[256];

    public AuthCipher()
    {
        byte baseKey = 157;
        byte baseKey2 = 98;
        for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
        {
            this.cipherKey1[i] = baseKey;
            this.cipherKey2[i] = baseKey2;
            baseKey = (15 + baseKey * 250) * baseKey + 19;
            baseKey2 = (121 - baseKey2 * 92) * baseKey2 + 109;
        }
        this.InCounter = 0;
        this.OutCounter = 0;
    }

    public unsafe void Encrypt(byte* src, int srcOffset, byte[] dst, int dstOffset, int length)
    {
        fixed (byte* pDst = &dst[dstOffset])
        {
            for (int i = srcOffset; i < srcOffset + length; i++)
            {
                pDst[i] = (src[i] ^ 171);
                pDst[i] = (byte)(pDst[i] >> 4 | (int)pDst[i] << 4);
                byte* expr_39 = pDst + i;
                *expr_39 ^= this.cipherKey2[this.InCounter >> 8];
                byte* expr_51 = pDst + i;
                *expr_51 ^= this.cipherKey1[(int)(this.InCounter & 255)];
                this.InCounter += 1;
            }
        }
    }

    public unsafe void Decrypt(byte[] src, int srcOffset, byte* dst, int dstOffset, int length)
    {
        fixed (byte* pSrc = &src[srcOffset])
        {
            for (int i = dstOffset; i < dstOffset + length; i++)
            {
                dst[i] = (pSrc[i] ^ 171);
                dst[i] = (byte)((int)dst[i] << 4 | dst[i] >> 4);
                byte* expr_35 = dst + i;
                *expr_35 ^= this.cipherKey2[this.OutCounter >> 8];
                byte* expr_4C = dst + i;
                *expr_4C ^= this.cipherKey1[(int)(this.OutCounter & 255)];
                this.OutCounter += 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Errors pop in:

```
baseKey = (15 + baseKey * 250) * baseKey + 19;
            baseKey2 = (121 - baseKey2 * 92) * baseKey2 + 109;

pDst[i] = (src[i] ^ 171);
dst[i] = (pSrc[i] ^ 171);
```

Tried already to read some other answers to this question bu no luck.
If any one could help me in understand whats wrong probably I know how to fix it :)

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: At least know which language you're using.

Comment: As a minor note: it is *usually* a good idea not to roll your own encryption / decryption code, but instead to use pre-existing well-known (and well analyzed) implementations. The `expr_39` etc here makes me think you're actually reverse-engineering this from somewhere...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Indeed, in C# (not C), the result of most operations on `byte` is (paradoxically, but it makes sense really) `int`. This means that you need to cast back to `byte`, but you need to think about what the rounding behaviour etc should be. A naïve fix would be:

```
baseKey = (byte)((15 + baseKey * 250) * baseKey + 19);
baseKey2 = (byte)((121 - baseKey2 * 92) * baseKey2 + 109);
...
pDst[i] = (byte)(src[i] ^ 171);
...
dst[i] = (byte)(pSrc[i] ^ 171);
```

But only you can validate those.

Answer (score 3):

If you're sure the result is in the byte then:

```
baseKey = Convert.ToByte((15 + baseKey * 250) * baseKey + 19);
baseKey2 = Convert.ToByte((121 - baseKey2 * 92) * baseKey2 + 109);
```

else you need to change `baseKey` and `baseKey2` to `int`

The [Ranges](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3f49ktz(v=vs.110).aspx) are below:

> Byte : 0 to 255
>
> Int : –2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647

Answer (score 1):

Intermediate calculations use some int type. Also your result is too large to be represented in a byte. The thing is you cannot take stuff this way.

One solution is to actually perform the explicit conversion (using cast operators or the Convert.ToByte function).

Answer (score 0):

You can not use `byte` to store number greater than 255:

```
baseKey = (15 + baseKey * 250) * baseKey + 19;
baseKey2 = (121 - baseKey2 * 92) * baseKey2 + 109;
```

Then your `baseKey > 255`, you have declare `int` variable to store that number.